# Is the author of the lyrics talking to a newborn baby or a young kid?

Tags: expressions, lyrics

Please elucidate:

---

Comfort - Deb Talan

### Lyrics Link : https://genius.com/Deb-talan-comfort-lyrics

*verse 1*

> When everyone has gone to sleep and you are wide awake
>   There's no one left to tell your troubles to
>   Just an hour ago, you listened to their voices
>   Lilting like a river over underground
>   And the light from downstairs came up soft like daybreak
>   Dimly as the heartache of a lonely child

*verse 4*

> So cry, why not? we all do
>   Then turn to one you love
>   And smile a smile that lights up all the room
>   Follow your dreams in through every out-door
>   It seems that's what we're here for

1. Who is the singer talking to? a newborn baby? or a kid?
2. who are 'their' referring to in first paragraph? (Third Line)
3. What does the 'Light' mean in first paragraph? (Fifth Line)
   Baby? Hope? Positive Thoughts?
4. What does 'It seems that's what we're here for' mean? (4-5 Line)
   I know what does 'it seems that's' mean
   but I can't understand 'what ~ for' part
   Follow your dreams in many ways.
   I think following own dream is why we are living?

---

I'm not fluent in English. I apologize if I come across as rude. I don't mean to.

Comment: It seems to me that the singer could well talking to himself.

Comment: We don't, as a general rule, do song lyrics on here. They're almost always open to interpretation. The only way to categorically answer your questions is with a quote from the songwriter, and that's not a *language* question.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Who is the singer talking to? a newborn baby? or a kid?

Could be either.

> 2. Whom do "their voices" belong to? (Line 3)

Folks in the house and/or people in general.

> 3. What does the 'Light' mean in line 5? The child? Hope? Positive thoughts?

No, as a matter of fact, just electrical light from downstairs (this is presumably a typical suburban house, with the bedrooms on the second floor).

> 4. What does 'It seems that's what we're here for' mean? (Lines 4-5) I know what does 'it seems that's' mean but I can't understand 'what ~
>      for' part Follow your dreams in many ways. I think following own dream
>      is why we are living?

The author implies that one's purpose in life is to "follow one's dreams through every out-door." Thus "That's what we're here for" means "that's what we've been put on earth for." Warning: it's a cliche.

Comment: Children don't typically tell their troubles to people. Only adults do that.  Also, if the baby is not asleep, neither are the parents, usually.

Comment: @Lambie Must be a very special child, then.